# Javascript promise pass param into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var getData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $.post( "data.php", { search: inputData }, function( data ) { //need to pass this
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    });

    if (data) {
        resolve(data);
    }
});

this.inputText.on('keyup', function(){
    var inputData = this.value; //I need to pass this into object

    getData.then(function(fromResolve){

        console.log(fromResolve);

    }).catch(function(fromReject){

        console.log(fromReject);

    });
});
```

I have a jQuery ajax post and I use promise to do something after it post back

my problem is how can I pass `this.value (keyup value)` into promise object, so `{ search: inputData }` can have value to post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `getData()` and actual function, so it can take parameters.

jQuery's `post()` already returns a promise, so you don't need to wrap again.

```
function getData( inputData ) {
  return $.post( "data.php", { search: inputData } );
}

this.inputText.on('keyup', function(){

    var inputData = this.value; 

    getData( inputData )
      .then(function(fromResolve){

        console.log(fromResolve);

       }).catch(function(fromReject){

        console.log(fromReject);

       });
});
```

Comment: i thought u cant return post

Comment: @BenjaminW The jQuery ajax functions return promises since quite a while, so you can easily return them and chain other calls.

Comment: so can i just do $.post().than()

Comment: if you use `then()`, yes ,-) - not the `e` instead of `a`. Overall jQuery (I think) uses it's own `Promise` implementation, which at some points differs from the native one.

Comment: 1 more question, while i test, it return string, but data.php actually send jason object

Comment: `$.ajax({  type: "POST",  url: "data.php",  data: { search: inputData },
  dataType: 'JSON' })` should give you the object parsed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `resolve` from the jQuery callback function.

```
var getData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $.post( "data.php", { search: inputData }, function( data ) { //need to pass this
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (data) { resolve(data); }
        else { reject(); }
    });
});
```